# Is it possible to use NSButton as a radio while setting images through the storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a collection of radio buttons created through the storyboard:

[image: Radio without Images]

Since these are all connected to the same outlet, they behave correctly as radio buttons, i.e. only one can be set to On state at once.

However, as soon as I add images (Image and Alternate properties) via the Attributes Inspector, Xcode switches these from Radio / Radio to Bevel / Switch. At this point, they no longer act as radio buttons but rather act as simple checkboxes, i.e. each has an independent On/Off state that doesn't affect the other states in the collection. No other change is made than adding images.

[image: Radio with Images]

I've tried manually changing the Style and Type of each button, hoping to find some magical combination that allows both radio behavior and images to co-exist. But that doesn't appear to be an option.

Am I missing something? Is this possible? My goal is to do this purely through the storyboard to prevent extensive code refactoring.

[image: Before/After]

Comment: sounds like a XCode bug.

Comment: I tried this with radio buttons created programmatically, but had the same result when setting the image(s), so it isn't just Xcode.  Since **NSMatrix** is deprecated, it looks like you'll have to duplicate the cell tracking behavior yourself (check out the [old NSMatrix documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000252-SW3)).

Comment: Actually I find NSMatrix still works great and remains the best way to do this and many other things. It has been deprecated prematurely. Just use it and be happy, is my advice.

Comment: Ha - “just use it and be happy”. Turns out that’s what I’m doing at this point. I’m pretty sure the proper NSMatrix / NSRadioButton replacement is the segmented control. But I’m pretty sure I need to build a custom implementation of it. In the meantime, I’ll continue living in the matrix.